# vba '91' error on return statement

Tags: xml, excel, vba, pointers

The following function I wrote is not working properly. I get the notorious '91' Object variable or With block variable not set error on the very last line of the block where I want to return the object. I do not understand why, as my input node indeed has the child node with the required id. The MsgBox tells me that the node has actually been found and therefore the variable res is set. Still I get the '91' error.

```
    Private Function getElementById(root As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, id As String) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Dim Children As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim Child As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim res As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    If (root.HasChildNodes = True) Then

        Set Children = root.ChildNodes

        For a_counter = 0 To (Children.Length - 1)

            Set Child = Children.Item(a_counter)

            If Child.Attributes.getNamedItem("id").Text = id Then

                Set res = Child
                found = True
                MsgBox "Found"

            End If

        Next a_counter

        If found = False Then
            MsgBox "Not Found"
            res = Nothing
        End If

    Else

        Set res = Nothing
        MsgBox "No Children"

    End If

    getElementById = res

    End Function
```

Comment: Solved, apparently Set getElementById = res should be used here.